# Transforming a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have an array with some structure which has to be recursively converted to the new structure. Please, consider the following example:

```
<?php

class Foo {

    public function getData()
    {
        return [
            'a' => [
                'fooa1' => 'bara1',
                'fooa2' => 'bara2',
                'fooa3' => 'bara3',
                'parent' => '0'
            ],
            'b' => [
                'foob1' => 'barb1',
                'foob2' => 'barb2',
                'foob3' => 'barb3',
                'parent' => '0'
            ],
            'c' => [
                'fooc1' => 'barc1',
                'fooc2' => 'barc2',
                'fooc3' => 'barc3',
                'parent' => 'b'
            ],
            'd' => [
                'food1' => 'bard1',
                'food2' => 'bard2',
                'food3' => 'bard3',
                'parent' => 'a'
            ],
            'e' => [
                'fooe1' => 'bare1',
                'fooe2' => 'bare2',
                'fooe3' => 'bare3',
                'parent' => 'c'
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function getDataPattern()
    {
        return [
            'a' => [
                'fooa1' => 'bara1',
                'fooa2' => 'bara2',
                'fooa3' => 'bara3',
                'children' => [
                    'd' => [
                        'food1' => 'bard1',
                        'food2' => 'bard2',
                        'food3' => 'bard3',
                        'parent' => 'a'
                    ],
                ]
            ],
            'b' => [
                'foob1' => 'barb1',
                'foob2' => 'barb2',
                'foob3' => 'barb3',
                'children' => [
                    'c' => [
                        'fooc1' => 'barc1',
                        'fooc2' => 'barc2',
                        'fooc3' => 'barc3',
                        'parent' => 'b',
                        'children' => [
                            'e' => [
                                'fooe1' => 'bare1',
                                'fooe2' => 'bare2',
                                'fooe3' => 'bare3',
                                'parent' => 'c'
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                ]
            ],
        ];
    }

    // DOESN'T WORK YET :(
    public function transformArrayToPattern()
    {
        $recordsArray = $this->getData();

        foreach ($recordsArray as $key => $recordArray) {
            if ($recordArray['parent'] !== '0') {
                $recordsArray[$key]['children'] = $recordArray;
                $this->transformArrayToPattern($recordArray);
            }
        }
        return $recordsArray;
    }
}
```

The levels and nesting can vary, but basically it's a flat structure on the input and I need such a nested structure in the end.

Do you have an idea, how it can be done? Thank you!

**EDIT: I'm sorry! I need to correct the example, because apparently we use only numerical IDs and not strings.** The correct format is like this:

```
    public function getData()
    {
        return [
            1 => [
                'fooa1' => 'bara1',
                'fooa2' => 'bara2',
                'fooa3' => 'bara3',
                'parent' => 0
            ],
            2 => [
                'food1' => 'bard1',
                'food2' => 'bard2',
                'food3' => 'bard3',
                'parent' => 1
            ],
            3 => [
                'fooc1' => 'barc1',
                'fooc2' => 'barc2',
                'fooc3' => 'barc3',
                'parent' => 1
            ],
        ];
    }
```

...but neither of the solutions till now can handle this. Would you mind to adjust the script for the numeric keys? Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it necessary to use your methods? Or it could be done manually?

Comment: The methods `getData()` and `getDataPattern()` are there just for the sake of example. The main transformation logic is the most important part and should happen in the function `transformArrayToPattern()`.

Comment: Not that this will resolve all issues, you have a bug at `if ($recordArray['parent'] !== 0)`, ... missing quotes on the 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php


class Foo {

    public function getData()
    {
        return [
            'a' => [
                'fooa1' => 'bara1',
                'fooa2' => 'bara2',
                'fooa3' => 'bara3',
                'parent' => '0'
            ],
            'b' => [
                'foob1' => 'barb1',
                'foob2' => 'barb2',
                'foob3' => 'barb3',
                'parent' => '0'
            ],
            'c' => [
                'fooc1' => 'barc1',
                'fooc2' => 'barc2',
                'fooc3' => 'barc3',
                'parent' => 'b'
            ],
            'd' => [
                'food1' => 'bard1',
                'food2' => 'bard2',
                'food3' => 'bard3',
                'parent' => 'a'
            ],
            'e' => [
                'fooe1' => 'bare1',
                'fooe2' => 'bare2',
                'fooe3' => 'bare3',
                'parent' => 'c'
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function getDataPattern()
    {
        return [
            'a' => [
                'fooa1' => 'bara1',
                'fooa2' => 'bara2',
                'fooa3' => 'bara3',
                'children' => [
                    'd' => [
                        'food1' => 'bard1',
                        'food2' => 'bard2',
                        'food3' => 'bard3',
                        'parent' => 'a'
                    ],
                ]
            ],
            'b' => [
                'foob1' => 'barb1',
                'foob2' => 'barb2',
                'foob3' => 'barb3',
                'children' => [
                    'c' => [
                        'fooc1' => 'barc1',
                        'fooc2' => 'barc2',
                        'fooc3' => 'barc3',
                        'parent' => 'b',
                        'children' => [
                            'e' => [
                                'fooe1' => 'bare1',
                                'fooe2' => 'bare2',
                                'fooe3' => 'bare3',
                                'parent' => 'c'
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                ]
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function transformArrayToPattern(){
        $data = $this->getData();
        $nodes = [];
        foreach($data as $node_name => $node_data){
            if(!isset($nodes[$node_data['parent']])) $nodes[$node_data['parent']] = [];
            $nodes[$node_data['parent']][] = $node_name;
        }

        //print_r($nodes);

        $result = [];

        foreach($nodes['0'] as $node_name){
            $result[$node_name] = $this->dfs($node_name,$nodes,$data);
            unset($result[$node_name]['parent']); // to unset parent 0
        }

        return $result;
    }

    private function dfs($node_name,$nodes,$data){
        if(!isset($nodes[$node_name])){
            return $data[$node_name];
        }

        $children = [];
        foreach($nodes[$node_name] as $kid_name){
            $children[$kid_name] = $this->dfs($kid_name,$nodes,$data);
        }

        return array_merge($data[$node_name],['children' => $children]);
    }
}


$o = new Foo();

print_r($o->transformArrayToPattern());
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/VLcgK

**Algorithm:**

- Well, you will have to first have hierarchy of nodes to make recursive calls.
- We do that in our first step and store all hierarchy in `$nodes`.
- Now, we only iterate on elements that have parent `0` because we will be recursively visiting it's sub nodes, so we can be always sure that we collect all nodes(data) in question.
- If a certain child node does not have any parent(meaning not present in `$nodes`), then it's the leaf child anyway. So, just return it's data without recursing further in `dfs()` method. Here, `dfs()` basically stands for [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you, please, take a look, why it cannot handle the numeric array keys as corrected in my last edit?

Comment: @QBnewmedia It does seem to work for me https://3v4l.org/qaVBW

Comment: Thank you, it really works. It fails, though, if the array begins at 0 and not at 1 as in my example. I fixed the beginning index for my array, so it's working fine now.

Comment: @QBnewmedia Glad to help, but can you a give a demo of which 0th index makes it fail?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet here is convert your data array to an object, containing further object properties, as objects are always passed by reference - this means the recursion is handled for you.

A shorthand way of converting an associative, nested, array to objects is to use `json_decode(json_encode($data))`.

As such, you could do something like the following with your `transformArrayToPattern()` method:

```
public function transformArrayToPattern()
{
    $recordsObject = json_decode(json_encode($this->getData()));

    foreach ($recordsObject as $key => $obj) {
        if ($obj->parent !== 0) {
            $recordsObject->{$obj->parent}->children[$key] = $obj;
        }
    }

    return array_filter((array) $recordsObject, function ($record) {
        return $record->parent === 0;
    });
}
```

This is basically adding a **reference** to the parent object to the `children` property of the class, and provides the nesting you're looking for. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

**Output**: https://3v4l.org/3flcp

Comment: That doesn't match what OP wants as an output.

Comment: Just edited as I realised I'd added the parents as children instead of the right way round

Comment: It still doesn't conform to it. See `getDataPattern()` method for expected output.

Comment: I changed the parents around for testing purposes. If they need it as an array they can convert it back again easily enough.

Comment: No, it's not about the datatype, but rather the structure itself. `b` should not come under `a`. See `getDataPattern()` method for expected output

Comment: Ok, you seemed to have a different initial structure itself in `getData()`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've changed that now. I also didn't notice the elements with parents shouldn't have been returned at the top level. Added a filter - thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you, please, take a look, why it cannot handle the numeric array keys as corrected in my last edit?